# "A valid signing identity matching this profile..." and Xcode error

Tags: xcode, identity, provisioning

Our company is setting up another development station for the same app that will be sent away.  I installed Xcode and tested the app in the simulator.  I downloaded the Certificate and Provision that worked fine on my other computer.  I selected the correct code signing identity and when I build it for a release to my iPad I get an error:

**Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: Person's Name (XXXXXXXX)' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain**

In organizer, I click on Provision Profiles and the provision profile I downloaded. Underneath I get the warning:

**A valid signing identity matching this profile could not be found in your keychain**

I've looked up many, many other people that had this problem, but all seem to resolve it by deleting the cert and provision, which I never want to do! i.e., what if I want to use the same provision and cert on two different machines, or many?

Comment: Did you add your iPad to the list of devices?

Comment: Ah, you mean in the provisioning profile. Yes I did. Please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also went through deleting, recreating, deleting, rinse-repeat - but the answer was simple.

I had the same problem and solved it very simply in XCode Organizer - I'm using Version 4. All I did was go to the top Library section and select Provisioning Profiles, and import the downloaded profiles that I had received in my Safari downloads named "name.mobileprovision".

Answer (score 2):

I think you just have to export the valid certs from the working computer, explained in this doc.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1618.html